# Changing Thread names

Tags: spark-java

I would like to change the thread-names (in the log outputs) for Spark. Currently they are named: `Thread-[ID]`. I would like to change the names to something like: `HTTP(S)-[ID]`. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess i found the answer myself. Just add a before filter that changes the thread name for you.

Here my handle-method:

```
public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
    String[] parts = thread.getName().split("-");
    if (parts.length != 2)
        return;

    thread.setName(request.scheme().toUpperCase() + "-" + parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: Nice. I guess you can do it anytime, not only in the `before` filter, right?

Comment: I guess you can do that whenever you want. But i would suggest to do it as soon as posible. Otherwise your log output from other filters may still keep those strange names.